# error when encoding row-level formula syntax error while declaring variable

Tags: reporting

I am very new to Salesforce Report and apology in advance if question sounds stupid. I got two date related columns: one is date only and other is DateTime. I tried to calculate the difference of two columns in number. When I used the subtract operator between two columns, I got following error:

```
Error when encoding row-level formula: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number
```

When I googled it,, I found that its due to different data types. Now I tried to convert datetime column into date. I looked few examples and I wrote the following line:

```
Date d = CLOSED_DATEONLY.date()
```

However, when I clicked on validate, I got the following message:

[image]

I'm not sure, where am I making the mistake. Could anyone help me in fixing the issue?

Comment: Remove the `Date d =` - there's no variables in formula syntax, you just need an expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`.

Comment: @MattLacey, When I removed it, I got an error: Error when encoding row-level formula: Unknown function CLOSED_DATEONLY.date. Check spelling.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your formula properly past that point! The code you found is using Apex, which is separate to the formula syntax in the platform. I can't remember what the date function is off the top of my head but it'll be something like `DATE(CLOSED_DATEONLY)`, but `CLOSE_DATEONLY` isn't a valid field name either, you might need a `__c` on the end of it? MIght be worth checkout out some of the Trailhead content on formulas.